# Is there a lint rule for python that automatically detects string concatenation and suggests string format?

Tags: python, lint, pylint, flake8

Since using string concatenation is a bad smell, I would like to detect automatically in the lint step of out CI pipeline and report to the developers.

For example, detect `"The user " + user.name + " is blocked"`, and suggest to use the `.format` method - `"The user {} is blocked".format(user.name)`.

I have looked for rules in *pylint* and *flake8*, but none attempt to detect this bad practice.

Comment: You could [roll out your own](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/).

Comment: "Since using string concatenation is a bad smell" is it? This seems like a perfectly reasonable place to use string concatenation.

Comment: Calling a function like `.format()` **MAY** result in an increase in processing time and overhead.

```In [2]: %timeit 'The user ' + username + ' is blocked'
The slowest run took 7.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: **149 ns per loop**```

VERSUS:

```In [3]: %timeit 'The user {} is blocked'.format(username)
The slowest run took 6.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: **322 ns per loop**```

Comment: You may propose the feature in pyflakes issue tracker https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues but expect to have to argue better than "since it is a bad smell". I personally find far more readable `"<" + name + ">"` than `"<{}>".format(name)`. Probably depends the context and intention. In other words, linting also uses developers judgment, not only CI rules.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: @E.Ducateme, I understand that it is not the best option from the point of view of optimization, but it is from the point of view of readability. I never saw a relevant impact in performance due to string formatting - however, it may depend on the type of code you are writing. Moreover, the usage of string concatenation makes localization almost impossible, since you break the sentences into fragments.

Comment: Also note: with Python's new `f` strings, there is an option that potentially makes boilerplate text even easier and more readable: `f"The user {username} is blocked"` will automagically insert the value of username in the place where the template placeholder is located, without the discontinuity introduced by the .format() method. learn more here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html